# Sum of Major Diagonal Matrix JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

I need to find the sum of the Major diagonal in a matrix in Java. My program works for Matrices such as 1x2, and 2x2 but when the rows become greater than the columns i.e. 3x2 my code throws an out of bounds exception. Is there any way I am able to fix it?

```
// sum of  major diagonal in matrix
public static int majorDiagonal(int[][] array){
    int sumMD = 0;
    for (int i = 0, j = 0, k = array.length; i < k && j < k; i++, j++) {
        sumMD += array[i][j];
    }
return sumMD;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need both `i` and `j`, since they always have the same value in your code.

Therefore, your continuation condition of `i < k && j < k` doesn't make much sense, because if `i` is less than `k`, then `j` will be too.

Change the continuation condition of your for loop to `i < k && i < array[0].length`.  This will check that `i` is less than both the number of columns and the number of rows, which is the condition that you want.

```
for (int i = 0, k = array.length; i < k && i < array[0].length; i++) {
    sumMD += array[i][i];
}
```

Comment: You can delete the `k = array.length; i < k` part. `i < array.length` will do fine

Comment: I can, yes.  But I wanted to make as few changes as possible to OP's original code - just enough to demonstrate the points I made in the text of the answer.